# Regex in JavaScript to search

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-group

I want to create a RegEx to search in JavaScript, the string I type is "AO it", so I want some sentences like "hit AO ah", "it AO",. Will be showed, I don't know how to do, and I wish when I type some special like ' (', '@#',... so it not show result.
I try RegEx as '.*it.*AO.*' but not match.

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex:

```
.*(AO it|it AO).*
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me submit a naive answer here as a baseline. Let's call "AO it" as the `target`.

Split `target` by space and you get a set of `tokens`. Then, show the user input if user input contains any of the element(s) in `tokens`.